# Determine which packages have broken after upgrading AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, yarnpkg

[image]I am working on a project that was developed on Angular v1.5.6.Now I want to upgrade the Angular v1.6.3.The problem is when I upgrade Angular to v1.6.3 the project breaks.

How can I know how many (and which) packages have broken for this upgradation?

Comment: Define 'project breaks'.

Comment: Angular.js doesn't have reliance upon packages and dependencies;  it generally has less than 5 javascript files.  if you are getting errors in your console, they would be the first step in identifying which part of your code isn't working properly.

Comment: @Claies Would you please check the screenshot.After upgrading to angular v1.6.3 that was the console.If you please help me to identify the problem.